# QWebEngine: How to get attribute value?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to rewrite my project writen in `QWebView` to `QWebEngineView`, but I don't know how to get the attribute value and assign it to a C++ variable. I think that I should use `QWebEnginePage::runJavaScript` function. But I don't know how.

For example, when I try to display value of element in console, I did this:

```
web->page()->runJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"login\").getAttribute(\"va‌​lue\")", []
(QVariant result)->void {
    qDebug()<<result.toString();
});
```

But It display nothing.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @nnb

For example, when I tried to display value of element in console, I did this:
    web->page()->runJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"login\").getAttribute(\"value\")", [](QVariant result)->void {qDebug()<<result.toString();});

But It display nothing.

Comment: @teaperr please edit your questions and add code samples there, not at comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the value of your element by connecting a slot to the `loadFinished` signal of `QWebView`. The code should look something like below.

```
void WebView::onPageLoadFinished(bool status)
{
    if(status)
    {
        QVariant value;
        QWebFrame* frame = this->page()->currentFrame();
        if (frame!=NULL)
        {
            QWebElement element = frame->findFirstElement("input[id=login]");
            value = element.attribute("value");
        }
        //In your case you can set a class variable instead of local variable value
    }
}
```

This method is clean and you can even add a url check right in the beginning of the SLOT and continue further only if the signal came from the url you are interested in.

EDIT: I just re-read your question and found that you want to implement it with `QWebEngine`. I am not sure if it can be done there. According to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html#unavailable-qt-webkit-apis) page, you can't access the internal elements. I would love to know if there is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

runJavaScript will definitely do it: Here is a functional example using pure Javascript to interact with a field named "email":

```
// This will set the value
this->_view->page()->runJavaScript(
    "document.querySelector('input[name=\"email\"]').value = \"JKLJKLJKL\";"
);

// This will retrieve the value
this->_view->page()->runJavaScript(
    "document.querySelector('input[name=\"email\"]').value;",
    [](const QVariant &result){
        qDebug() << "Value is: " << result.toString() << endl;
    }
);
```

Remember that the scope of the QVariant is limited to the callback, if you need to use the returned value outside of the function, you will want to pass a variable *that will survive until callback is called* in the [].

Answer (score -1):

There is the direct access to DOM attributes/properties in JS:

```
document.getElementById("login").va‌​lue
```

Also I would recommend to use jQuery (take a look at fancybrowser example). Code for set/get value of login input is:

```
if( qt.jQuery( 'input#login' ).length ) // can be omitted if you are sure that DOM element is ready 
{
    qt.jQuery( 'input#login' ).attr( 'value', currentUserName ); //-- set value
    return qt.jQuery( 'input#login' ).attr( 'value' ); //-- get
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works fine.

```
_view->page()->runJavaScript("document.querySelector(input[name=\"email\"]).value");
```

Just add your callback as second parameter. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine.

```
_view->page()->runJavaScript("document.querySelector(input[name=\"email\"]).value");
```

Just add your callback as second parameter to get the value. I hope this helps you.